# Does Selenium Grid handsover the Node after connection?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

As shown in this diag:
[image]

All the connections from the Selenium Tests(client) should go directly to Selenium HUB, then it will forward the request to an appropriate Node, and return the response.

But what i am observing, that after finding an appropriate Node, the client is trying to communicate directly to the Node.

But in case, the nodes are in a private network and are accesible only by the Selenium HUB and NOT ACCESSIBLE by the Selenium Tests(client) then the subsequent calls fails.

[image]

Any idea on how to force all the subsequent calls through the Selenium HUB only?

**EDIT**

The problem might be something different. My hub is running on 192.168.0.100(with another ip as 10.0.0.2).

So when i am connecting to 192.168.0.100 from my .Net RemoteWebDriverClient, after connecting to the appropriate node, it is using the another ip of the client(10.0.0.2) which is not accessible from my system.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO, it doesn't. The Grid remain active throughout the connection.

The ip 10.0.0.2 was of the same selenium HUB machine only. The .net & java implementations of selenium `RemoteWebDriver` clients were switching to the `location` header parameter after the initial handshake. This is may be due to the .Net and Java HTTPClient implementations.